# How can I add some sort of trigger variable to a trigger pipeline in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, triggers, environment-variables, azure-data-factory

I have multiple pipelines and they are executed simultaneously with 1 trigger. I want to change a setting (a variable for each of the pipelines), what is a easy and efficient way to to this?

This variable, name it 'testvariable', has to be changed sometimes. When that happens I don't want to dive into every pipeline (more than 30 pipelines) separately to change the value of this 'testvariable'. Is there a way to add this 'testvariable' with a value into the trigger, so I can easily change that 'trigger' variable and it would affect all the underlying pipelines?

Comment: what is the type your trigger? Can you explain your ask with an example for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider creating a parent pipeline and inside that parent pipeline, you should consider using `execute pipeline activities` to run child pipelines.

Now in the parent pipeline, have a parameter `testVariable` and assign a trigger on top of `parent pipeline`. This parameter value can be used according in all the `child pipelines` during execution.